# How to limit movement on Y axis in this script

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mask : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update  
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame  
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
        {
            this.transform.Translate(Vector3.down *0.01f);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
        {
            this.transform.Translate(Vector3.up *0.01f);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my script that I would like to limit.
You can use any metod or/and numbers of limitations.
Thanks to anyone who will help me ;D.

Answer (score 0):

Set MinY and MaxY to desired edge values. SerializeField attribute is for possibility to set these values from Unity properties explorer.

```
[SerializeField]
private int MinY;

[SerializeField]
private int MaxY;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(this.transform.position.y - 0.01f, MinY, MaxY), this.transform.position.z);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(this.transform.position.y + 0.01f, MinY, MaxY), this.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```